# M2Crypto doesn't install in venv, or swig doesn't define __x86_64__ which breaks compiling against OpenSSL

Tags: python, linux, openssl, swig, virtualenv

I'm trying to install the Python M2Crypto package into a virtualenv on an x86_64 RHEL 6.1 machine. This process invokes swig, which fails with the following error:

```
$ virtualenv -q --no-site-packages venv
$ pip install -E venv M2Crypto==0.20.2
Downloading/unpacking M2Crypto==0.20.2
  Downloading M2Crypto-0.20.2.tar.gz (412Kb): 412Kb  downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package M2Crypto
Installing collected packages: M2Crypto
  Running setup.py install for M2Crypto
    building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
    swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
    swig -python -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include -includeall -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
    /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:31: Error: CPP #error ""This openssl-devel package does not work your architecture?"". Use the -cpperraswarn option to continue swig processing.
    error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/lorin/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/lorin/venv/build/M2Crypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-BFiNtU-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/lorin/venv/include/site/python2.6:
```

I've got OpenSSL 1.0.0 installed via RPM packages from RedHat.

The part of /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h that causes the error looks like this:

```
#if defined(__i386__)
#include "opensslconf-i386.h"
#elif defined(__ia64__)
#include "opensslconf-ia64.h"
#elif defined(__powerpc64__)
#include "opensslconf-ppc64.h"
#elif defined(__powerpc__)
#include "opensslconf-ppc.h"
#elif defined(__s390x__)
#include "opensslconf-s390x.h"
#elif defined(__s390__)
#include "opensslconf-s390.h"
#elif defined(__sparc__) && defined(__arch64__)
#include "opensslconf-sparc64.h"
#elif defined(__sparc__)
#include "opensslconf-sparc.h"
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
#include "opensslconf-x86_64.h"
#else
#error "This openssl-devel package does not work your architecture?"
#endif
```

gcc has the right variable defined:

```
$ echo | gcc -E -dM - | grep x86_64
#define __x86_64 1
#define __x86_64__ 1
```

But apparenty swig doesn't, since this is the line that's failing:

```
swig -python -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include -includeall -o \
  SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
```

Is there a way to fix this by changing something in my system configuration? M2Crypto gets installed in a virtualenv as part of a larger script I don't control, so avoiding mucking around with the M2Crypto files would be a good thing.

Comment: There is [`fedora_setup.sh`](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/fedora_setup.sh) but it requires mucking around with the M2Crypto files.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Not familiar with that, can you provide more details in a complete answer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

M2Crypto supplies a fedora_setup.sh script to handle the problems with Fedora/RL/CentOs releases, but pip, of course, doesn't know anything about it.

After the pip install fails, it leaves the downloaded stuff in the venv/build/M2Crypto directory. do this:

```
cd <path-to-your-venv>/venv/build/M2Crypto
chmod u+x fedora_setup.sh
./fedora_setup.sh build
./fedora_setup.sh install
```

This has worked in my install process

Comment: As of today (version 1.5.6) pip cleans up the build directory, so there's nothing to do therein anymore.

Answer (score 11):

You just don't have `swig` installed.

**Try:**

```
sudo yum install swig
```

**And then:**

```
sudo easy_install M2crypto
```

Comment: On Mac OS X 10.9.4 I installed swig using MacPorts (`sudo port install swig`). I also had to install Python's markupsafe globally (`sudo pip install markupsafe`), because swig depends on it (`.../markupsafe/_speedups.so: Error opening or reading file`).

Comment: Looks like with MacPorts we also need to install swig-python (`sudo port install swig-python`).

Comment: This worked for me when I had a similar problem on Ubuntu (though of course using apt-get instead of yum).

Answer (score 9):

I did this and it works very well :

```
env SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -I/usr/include/openssl" pip install M2Crypto
```

Of course you have to install swigg with `sudo yum install swig` before

Answer (score 5):

If you are seeing this and are on Ubuntu, use apt-get instead of pip to avoid this issue.

`apt-get install python-m2crypto`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue where `/usr/include/openssl` was missing `opensslconf.h`
(source https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=733644#10)

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl/opensslconf.h /usr/include/openssl
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a repository where "pip install" works:

https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto

Comment: You could try this: pip install git+https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto.git

As I'm planning to wrap up some changes to M2Crypto that are floating around into new release(s) that will end up in pypi, you can safely use the same git tree at the moment.

Comment: "pip install git+github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto.git" fails with "ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'git+github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto.git', 'at', '+github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto.git')" on my Ubuntu 10.04 system.

Comment: The formatting. Do add https and colons and slashes in front of github.com

Comment: Thanks for this, this is supremely helpful for keeping our build process sane.

Comment: This doesn't work for a virtual environment on Ubuntu.

Comment: Which ubuntu? Will try in a sec.

Comment: Try now. https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto/commit/134e1d9e7dde2e63064afa2f7ef82df8107889ea should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo yum install m2crypto
```

worked for me to get around this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found a new way to fix this problem in centos5.8, try it.

`vim setup.py`

```
def finalize_options(self):
  ...
  self.swig_opts.append('-includeall') # after this line
  self.swig_opts.append('-I/usr/include/openssl') # add here
```

then `python setup.py install` will work.

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD I had to install Swig (the obvious part) as well (by `sudo pkg install swig`), but Swig 2.0 executable was named `swig2.0` and handle `swig` resulted in `command not found`. Solution: symlink Swig 2.0 to handle `swig`:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/swig2.0 /usr/local/bin/swig
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like not having swig is the problem, as @LeoC said.

For those on MacOS, I'd recommend downloading swig via a package manager like homebrew because it's cleaner.

I.e. you'd run

```html
brew install swig
```